# Correct encoding for unicodePwd in Active Directory

Tags: encoding, active-directory

Putting it shortly, what is the right character encoding for the **unicodePwd** attribute in Active Directory? UCS-2? UTF-16? Is there any reason to choose UTF-16 over UCS-2?

Now, explaining a bit:

I was having trouble setting the **unicodePwd** attribute in Active Directory using PHP's **ldap_mod_replace()**, until I (sort of) found out the right format for it, which is enclosed in double quotes and encoded in UCS-2/UTF-16 Little Endian (and also base64 encoded, in the case of putting it in a LDIF file).

While the underlying problem was solved, I could not get my head around the fact I kept seeing both encodings being mentioned as correct around the internet.

I am being very pedantic here, but is anyone able to point the right character encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct character encoding is UTF-16LE. Additionally, the password must be enclosed in double quotation marks. I am not sure where the UCS-2 encoding was mentioned, never seen it personally.

#### Example

User's password: *test*
Quoted password: *"test"*
UTF-16LE representation:

```
0x22 "
0x00
0x74 t
0x00
0x65 e
0x00
0x73 s
0x00
0x74 t
0x00
0x22 "
0x00
```

Further details may be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Use UTF-16LE instead of UCS-2LE

Answering my own question: All I had to do was try to set a password in UTF-16 containing a 4 bytes character, intended to see whether such character would be correctly recognized and accepted in a password when trying to logon.

In order to do so, I put in the middle of an ordinary password a rather strange (to me) japanese character, tried to set the password and looked at the reaction.

Turns out, it did accept the **ldap_mod_replace()** call with the awkward password. Not only that, it accepted when I tried to logon using the password I had just set with the japanese character in the middle.

In conclusion, (if I am not mistaken) this goes to show that Active Directory's **unicodePwd** attribute not only accepts UTF-16 characters otherwise not present in UCS-2, it also behaves as it should when a password contains a 4 bytes in length character.